# Testing if jQueryTools has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-tools

How can I test if [jQueryTools library](http://jquerytools.org/) has been loaded like we can do in jQuery or jQueryUI?

As I use cdn to load the libraries, I have to be sure of are properly loaded.
With jQuery I use this code (using jQuery() function):

```
if (jQuery) {
  // library loaded
}
```

So I load the library using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

**Anything similar with jQueryTools?**

Comment: make it simple, add ui library just below jquery base file.

Comment: Couldn't you check `if (jQuery.overlay)` or a similar feature of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check and see if one of the methods in that plugin exists like this example:

```
if(!jQuery().overlay) {
     // plug-in is not installed
}
```

Comment: `if (!jQuery.fn.overlay)` doesn't execute any function nor create an empty jQuery object and should work as well.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery.fn.tabs || document.write('<script src="jquery.tools.min.js"><\/script>')</script>